# The problem that the data of RecyclerView changes randomly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, epoxy

## (Image 1 & Image 2)

[image]
[image]

---

## (Image 3)

[image]

---

I'm currently using the `Epoxy library` instead of `RecyclerView`.
However, since `Epoxy` is built on the basis of `RecyclerView`, let's just call it `RecyclerView`.

***Problem 1 . (Image 1 & Image 2)***

> When i return to another screen after entering a value in the `EditText` of the `RecyclerView item`, the entered data is moved randomly.

***Problem 2 . (Image 3)***

> After adding enough `items` to be scrollable, i also enter values ​​into the `EditText`.
> And if i scroll down and come back,  the data is moved to a random location.

Please tell me what is the reason and what is the proper solution.

Comment: RecyclerView recycles views. If you don't back up the text of an EditText to the model item data as it is typed and restore it in `onBindView`, you'll just see previous text that was in the view when it was last recycled. I don't use Epoxy, but this issue seems to address how to do this in Epoxy: https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/issues/426

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how the content of the git link relates to my question

Comment: It's exactly what you're trying to do. Feed back EditText changes into the model so they persist when they scroll away and come back. The developer explanation of how to do it looks very complicated. I don't use Epoxy. Maybe it just isn't a good tool when you have interactive widgets in your RecyclerView. From browsing the Epoxy documentation, it looks like something that helps if you have multiple view types and data binding, but otherwise makes things a lot more complicated than ListAdapter. It does predate ListAdapter. Also, there is ConcatAdapter now which can combine list types easily.

Comment: I mean, I didn't understand the question itself in that link.. The answer to that question seems to be similar to what I'm trying to ask, but I didn't understand the question itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're overriding `getItemViewType`, `getItemId` and `getItemCount` properly.