# Inside recyclerview i have an cardview inside edittext problem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Inside recyclerview I implement cardview Inside this cardview have 1 edittext, recyclerview contains 10 rows of cardview, but the problem is if I edit 1st row of cardview, it will also reflect in 10th row of cardview editext,if I edit 2nd cardview then it will reflect 9th cardview, what can I do ,please help me out...

Comment: Have you tried adding stable ids via recyclerview adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Just Override `getItemId` in your Recycler Adapter.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: How can I solve it please give me some solutions, in recyclerview 5 cardview is working correctly whenever I editthe the value and set the value if I add more than 5 then the value from 1 row of cardview is showing in 9th row of cardview..value is showing in both cardview

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you're overriding `getItemViewType`, `getItemId` and `getItemCount` properly.

([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69993183/11880323))